# Can/should I support both Node.js and Typescript from the same codebase?

Tags: node.js, typescript

I'm not very familiar with Typescript, but I'm trying to determine if it's possible (or even makes sense) to support both Typescript and Node.js from the same codebase.

Is it enough to just provide a declaration file (`.d.ts`) for my library? Or will the Typescript support need to be even more integrated in to my code? If it helps, I'm referring to [this](https://github.com/scottwrobinson/camo) project specifically.

Any examples of open source projects that support both would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure if it is possible, but not sticking to one technology introduces unnecessary complexity leading to errors. Will it really be beneficial to introduce Typescript if say 40% of your code remains in plain JS? Is it really that bad to then do all of it in JS and save on headaches fixing interoperability issues and finding people who know and want to know what Typescript is about. IMHO the benefit on node is that you use JS on both server and client side, dropping it on either of them makes it difficult to follow why you get stuck in JS at all. Do not like JS, go for dart instead :)

Comment: Once you know what typescript is you'll know if it makes sense for you.  There is an abundance of d.ts definitions (look into TSD) so it's very natural to consume javascript from typescript.

Comment: @Oleg I don’t want to be mean, but you’re mistaken. Your comment will only confuse people who aren’t familiar with TypeScript, JavaScript, and Node.js.

Comment: @thoughtrepo I posted a comment and not an answer to the question. In such a way I have expressed my own opinion without pretending to deliver an answer. I am sorry, but I do have a right to have my own opinion and this platform allows me to express it in comments. I might well be wrong in my own opinion, because I really do not have experience with TypeScript, but do have fairly substantial experience with Node and JS and the comment is very general. Finally, if I am wrong with something specific then tell in what, otherwise you are plainly rude.

Comment: @Oleg I apologize if I offended you, I was trying to avoid that kind of response. I never said you didn’t have a right to your opinion, but you’re mistaken. Since you asked, I’ll explain. TypeScript is not a completely separate technology from JavaScript. It is a superset of JavaScript. TypeScript can be used seamlessly beside JavaScript.

Comment: Interoperability issues are minimal. Writing a TypeScript definition file for a JavaScript project doesn’t affect the JavaScript code at all, so there are no headaches. Projects written in TypeScript can run anywhere JavaScript can run. You don’t need to drop support for Node.js or any other runtimes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to clarify, TypeScript is just JavaScript in the end. It's not a runtime environment like Node.js.

Your project will work with TypeScript as is, you don't *need* to do anything for your project to be used with code written in TypeScript.

However, for the TypeScript compiler (TSC) to understand your project, you will need to provide a definition file.

[DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped) is a repository that contains TypeScript definitions for many libraries written in JavaScript. Use those as examples.

There's no need to define all of the inner workings of the project, just the public API. See [Writing Definition Files](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook/blob/master/pages/Writing%20Definition%20Files.md) for more tips.

Additionally TSC will look for a property named `typings` in `package.json` that points to a definition file. View [Typings for npm packages](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Typings-for-npm-packages) for details. Your definition file should be distributed with your npm package.

As a side note, a definition file can used in VS Code to provide type checking in all JavaScript projects, not just TypeScript.

Comment: Thanks for all the great info. It looks like using DefinitelyTyped is the preferred method. Do you think it would be more convenient if I made a fork of my project to provide the .d.ts file (so users don't need to add another dependency), or just include it in the main codebase? Trying to decide what makes the most sense for everyone. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it enough to just provide a declaration file (.d.ts) for my library? Or will the Typescript support need to be even more integrated in to my code?

This is perfectly fine. In fact check out `immutablejs` from facebook [link](https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js/). Its written in JavaScript and just provides a `.d.ts` in the repo : https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js/tree/master/type-definitions That is linked from [`package.json`](https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js/blob/5138e1d37daa63c03142ef2e5a8b2076c250311e/package.json#L18-L20)

Note that if you have your project in TypeScript, there are easier ways, checkout : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/node/nodejs.html